# What can I do to center the image and set the width in an already given template?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, diagrams, width

The problem I am having is that I am not able to position this image properly into the page. For my uni project, for which I have an overleaf template already, I am trying to insert this picture but it is not centered and also the selected width is not respect.
The "page-space" is defined by: \usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
The width has to be 75mm, as seen in the code. I have tried to change the width however or scale the picture, the size of it does not change, but only the picture is moved either more to the right corner(for lower values) or more to the left(for higher values). I have no errors regarding the picture, only some warnings about \hbox which, as far as I know should not influence the functionality of the code. I have tried to set the width to \textwidth, the image has the same size, appears more in the page but still not entirely, therefore still not centered. If I upload it in an empty document it works, but I need to work with the given template.

[image: radius and ulna]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=75mm]{radiusandulna.jpg}
\caption[radiusandulna]{radiusandulna}
\label{fig-buch}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: strong text]

Comment: It is impossiible to debug the fragments you have posted, something is inserting negative space to make the image over-print but that is not in code you have shown. You have scaled the image to 75mm but we have no knowledge about the width of the space where you have placed the image (but if it is too large it will over-print t the right, not to the left as shown). Please post an example that  shows the problem, then someone can debug.

Comment: The already defined space is given in the code by this I suppose \usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}. I guess this is the defined space for the image.

Comment: well that is a little bit more information, about the page size but not enough for anyone to reproduce the problem. Are you setting in two column for example. Ideally your example should start `\documentclass` end `\end{document}` and use `example-image` as the image and produce the problem over-printing.

Comment: I have now edited the question so that all the information is there

Comment: No, the posted code just produces `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.` Also you are asking how to stop an image over-printing text but your example code has no text that is over-printed. The example should be an example of the problem.

Comment: the code should work now.  The code I have is already given by the university. it is structured in such a way, that there is a main.tex file and some other .tex filles (the chapters basically) which are then called in the main one. there are also some "definitions" .tex files where the packages are imported and the needed parameters are defined. As mentioned before, if I upload the whole thing into a blank document it works out perfectly. There is probably some parameter defined wrongly somewhere in the given files but I do not know what to look for in order to correct it

Comment: sorry I give up, we try and help here but if you just post an image showing wrong output and code of an unrelated document that does not demonstrate the problem shown in the image then it is basically impossible to guess what is wrong.  If you have `text text text\hspace{-5cm}\includegraphics{file.jpg}`  then the image will over-print the text and the fix is to remove the negative space. Somewhere in code not shown you have code doing exactly that. But we can not guess where if you show no code.

Comment: you can _always_ make a small example to post here. start from a copy of your document, change the image to `example-image` delete everything after the image, delete as much as you can before the image, replace any `\input` by copying the code directly to the main file, delete any packages not used in the remaining example. Check at each stage the problem still shows. If you delete something and the problem goes, you found the solution, if the problem still shows post the resulting example here.

Comment: Thank you very much. the problem was \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}. After deleting the [dvips] part it worked.

Comment: you _must_ have had errors from that if you were using pdflatex. Never ignore error messages!!!